# What's the song when Gon is on the ship to take the hunter exam?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

In *Hunter x Hunter*, when Gon goes away from his home to take the hunter exam, I think there's a music in the ship when Gon says "a storm is coming" and the captain says "I have only seen one guy who can do that".

What is that song?

Comment: Could you also mention the episode no., and possible the timestamp?

Comment: which hunter x unter version ? 1999 or 2013 ?

Answer (score 1):

It's Ohayou Harmonica, you can check the scene here : [Ohayou Harmonica - Gon Predicting a Storm](https://youtu.be/PyBL4ak4GhQ)